# Sorting: composition vs external sorting facility

Tags: java, sorting, composition

Reading a book I found this solution for sorting my own data set:

```
class QuickSort {
    public String[] sort(String[] array) {
        // Implementation
    }
}

class MyDataSet {
    private String array[];
    private QuickSort sorting;

    // Rest of the code here
}
```

I would have instead used something like this:

```
class QuickSort {
    public static MyDataSet sort(MyDataSet) {
        // Implementation
    }
}

class MyDataSet {
    private String array[];

    // Rest of the code here
}

MyDataSet sortedDataSet = quicksort.sort(myDataSetInstance);
```

In the first case I would use composition, in the second a completely external solution.

The second case is also similar to the Collections.sort() into the collection framework.

What are the differences and the advantages of each method? Which one is better to use depending on which context?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to sort a normal String array BUT not a collection of user defined objects. So the best approach will be to create a Utility class and provide a static method.